# How to create partitioned Athena table with Sagemaker Feature Store

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, feature-store, aws-feature-store

I'm using Sagemaker Feature Store and trying to create an Offline Feature Store. During the process, Sagemaker creates an Athena table. However, I notice that this table is not partitioned, and when I create a query, it takes forever.

How can I use Sagemaker Feature Store to create a Athena table with partition?

Comment: Hi Paulo, I stumbled across your post because we have the same issue. Did you find a solution?